# Unable to model an AR(1) process

Tags: time-series, arima

This is my AR(1) series where X(t) = 0.9 * X(t-1):

```
series = [1000]
for i in range(25):
    series.append(series[-1] * 0.9)
ar1_series = np.array(series)
print(ar1_series)

[1000.    900.    810.    729.    656.1   590.49  531.44  478.3   430.47
  387.42  348.68  313.81  282.43  254.19  228.77  205.89  185.3   166.77
  150.09  135.09  121.58  109.42   98.48   88.63   79.77   71.79]
```

[image]

I am trying to fit an AR(1) model on this series:

```
model = ARIMA(ar1_series, order=(1, 0, 0))

            coef        std err     z       P>|z|   [0.025      0.975]
const       558.0533    400.588     1.393   0.164   -227.084    1343.191
ar.L1.y     0.9921      0.011       89.024  0.000   0.970       1.014
```

This is how the model forecasts this series (blue is actual, red is forecasted):

[image]

Why is the AR(1) coefficient estimated by the model to be '0.9921' and not '0.9' as defined in the series?

Comment: Your series is generated with the noise set to zero, making it an atypical AR(1) process. I wonder if that could be among the reasons for an imprecise estimate. Have you tried the same procedure on another sample?

Comment: Already tried with noise first. Didn't work. ☹️

Comment: The reason for the discrepancy is that your sample is not from an AR(1) process, specifically, the first observation does not come from the stationary distribution of the process.

Comment: @JarleTufto Can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Had to make four changes:

1. Starting element is sampled from a Gaussian distribution with variance as derived [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245579/finding-variance-of-ar-process).
2. Added error terms following a Gaussian distribution
3. Increased number of samples from 25 to 10000
4. Removed the constant term while fitting by setting trend='nc' (statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA)

[image]

```
phi = 0.9
sigma = 1

series = [gauss(0, sqrt(sigma**2 / (1 - phi**2)))]
for i in range(10000):
    series.append(series[-1] * phi + gauss(0, sigma))
ar1_series = np.array(series)
model = ARIMA(ar1_series, order=(1, 0, 0))
model.fit(trend='nc')

            Coef.   Std.Err.    t           P>|t|   [0.025      0.975]
ar.L1.y     0.9001  0.0049      185.0123    0.0000  0.8906      0.9097
```

Comment: You're still not sampling $X_1$ from its stationary distribution as the stationary variance of $X_t$ is not the same as the variance of the error term.  You can derive the correct variance by taking variance of both sides of the equation $X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ and then using the fact that you have second-order stationary process.

Comment: @JarleTufto Thanks. Hope I got it right this time around...